# Unable to select option from react-select drop down Robotframework

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

There is a dropdown named "sampleType" where there are several values "AB1, AB2, .. AB6".

When I manually click on the drop down AB1 is selected by default.

I need to select other values i.e. AB2-AB6 as per the user input.

I have gone through many questions here but dint find anything appropriate.

Below is the HTML snippet.

Please help & Thanks in Advance!

```
<div class="react-select" id="sampleType" role="presentation">
<div class="Select react-select has-outline has-value Select--single">
<input name="sampleType" type="hidden" value="AB1">
<div class="Select-control">
<span class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-sampleType--value" aria-label="Select Menu. AB1 selected.">
<div class="Select-value">
<span class="Select-value-label" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="react-select-sampleType--value-item">AB1</span>
</div>
<div aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="" aria-activedescendant="react-select-sampleType--value" aria-disabled="false" class="Select-input datagrid-row-actions" role="combobox" style="border: 0px none; width: 1px; display: inline-block;" tabindex="0"></div>
</span>
<span class="Select-arrow-zone">
<span class="Select-arrow"></span></span></div></div><div class="footer-height" role="alert"><div class="error"></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Add your code trials and errors to the question

Answer (score 0):

From your snippet it looks like you are using a combo box with the name attribute of "sampleType"? Then you can actually type in the desired input. It would look something like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_name("sampleType").send_keys(valueFromUserInput)
```

You need to target the "input" tag, and send the inpput (send_keys) to it

Comment: That dint help. I am trying it in robotframework and I tried using PressKeys, it dint fail but there was no action on the webpage. Even when I open it manually and type in keys it doesn't filter or got the matching value.